# How does match works in xsl template?

Tags: xml, xslt, wsdl, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an xsl like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="wsdl:definitions">
        <!-- code here -->
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

in this xsl , what does this line do:

```
<xsl:template match="wsdl:definitions">
```

from my understanding its going to strictly match `wsdl:definitions` tags which is like this `<wsdl:definitions>` in the given xml (correct me if I'm wrong here).

But I was literally confused the moment, I give this input xml:

```
<xxx:definitions xmlns:xxx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xxxx1="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl"  >
</xxx:definitions>
```

it still matches `<xxx:definitions>` and does the transformation as needed. How this can be possible given that in my xsl sheet I have given it to match `wsdl:definitions`? Is match something to do with `xmlns` of the given input xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace prefix is just a name for the URI. If the URIs match the namespaces are identical. The `xmlns` adds a prefix to the URI. There can even be many prefixes for the same namespace in a single document.

So you are allowed to use whatever prefixes you want for the namespaces and the XSL will always match them properly. This will help with documents originating from different sources not needing to use the same prefixes and still be understood.

Comment: So since the URI `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/` matches in both documents it works, right? This has nothing to do with `match` , right?

Comment: @Ant's Yes. Since both have a prefix for that URI the match will consider them equal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, make sense now!